# Resources on representations theory and harmonic analysis

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm studing the representation theory of the group [$SL(2,R)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)) from the book "Lorentz group and harmonic analysis" of Ruhl, in particular I'm interest in chapter 5 and 6. I'm a master students and I don't have enough mathematical background to understand well all the arguments of those chapters. I ask you some resources (notes, books ...) to start with.
The topics are:

1. The representation theory of $SL(2,R)$, in particular to find all the unitary irreducible  repr. of it. (discrete series, principal and complementary)
2. The harmonic analysis on this group (I haven't seen harmonic analysis over groups)

Please help me if you can.

p.s.)
I think also that this book explain in a strange/old fashion these topics, cause I found something on the web but it wasn't be so helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at Serge Lang's SL$_2$(R)?